# Gradle: main source set depends on other source sets?

Tags: gradle

Gradle: is it a good ideas for main source set to depend on other source sets?  For example,

```
src/main
src/foo
src/bar
```

Source set main depend on foo and bar. Any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing but you might want to peek at the source code in my [java flavours plugin](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours).

Each flavour has `src/$flavour/java` and `src/$flavour/resources` directories by default and has a separate compile, test and jar task. Each flavour extends from the "main" source set so the main classes are on the compile classpath etc, but you can also override classes and resources from the "main" source set

Interesting code [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/javaflavours/JavaFlavoursExtension.groovy#L22)